# Improving terminal server performance for a specfic app

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, terminal-server

We have a windows 2003 terminal server running 2X application load balancign that is hosting a client's application that is accessed by around 50 users.

Each user has there own database.  The database is a file based database.  The application is developed under Delphi so I think the database may be BDE based.

As you can imagine, there is probably quite a lot of disk i/o.  Here are some of the perfmon settings.

Logged in users (average) 20 - 25
CPU Utilization (average) 80 - 100%
Disk Queue Length (average) 1.6
% Disk time (average) 111
Page faults/sec (average) 1400

The application takes on average about a minute to load up.

As usual, the budget is tight.  Is there basic windows performance tuning tips that people can recommend to improve things before we fork out on more RAM etc.

Server is a 2.8GHz Xeon with 3GB of RAM.

Comment: What's the perf like with only one user logged on?  This needs to be tested on the TS itself rather than taking a copy of the app to a workstation.

Comment: Performance for a single instance is quite reasonable.

Comment: What average's are those performance metrics based on - 1 sec, 30 sec, 1 minute?

Comment: Running over around 10 minutes.  But, we frequently get performance related complaints.

Comment: Have you sorted this problem out Matt? If not those perfmon stats aren't that helpful without some more context. How many disks are there in the servers and how are the allocated, i.e. do the database files live on their own disks?

Comment: As mentionned above, we need more info. Also, it is very possible that the server needs to be upgraded. 25 users on a machine with only 3GB of RAM running an IO intensive application seems to not be enough. You would possibly be fine by getting a machine with a faster CPU (remember that nowadays Quad cores etc are super cheap), more ram, and you could even consider putting a small (or pair of) SSDs to store that particular data, if you don't have access to other fast storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

Actually the problem has been resolved.  The improvement came in the form of a new server with faster SCSI disks, an extra dual core CPU's (compared to a single dual core in the old server) and also twice the memory of the old server.

While still not the fastest machine on the planet, it made an enormous difference to the application performance.

I think quite possibly the biggest performance boost came from the faster disks and increased memory because in the old server there was a lot of virtual memory being used and you can imagine how this would really hurt a heavily disk based database application.